# ASP.NET cookies with multiple values - how to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I am using ASP.NET and C#.

I must read a cookie called "TheCookie".............

TheCookie have about 3 values in them. Cookie1, Cookie2 and Cookie3.

How would i get the value in code to read Cookie2's value inside "TheCookie"?

This is how i would read when a cookie only have 1 value, but i dont know what to do when there are multiple vales in the cookie.......... Code for VB.NET

```
Dim userCookie As HttpCookie
userCookie = Request.Cookies("UserEmail")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to explain this furthur, I think.  A cookie can only have one value.  You could have set mutiple cookies or set a single cookies value as an object with multipole properties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You set them via

(C#)

```
Response.Cookies["TheCookie"]["Cookie1"] = "Hello World";
```

(VB)

```
Response.Cookies("TheCookie")("Cookie1") = "Hello World"
```

and read them like so

(C#)

```
string myValue = Request.Cookies["TheCookie"]["Cookie1"];
```

(VB)

```
Dim myValue As String
myValue = Request.Cookies("TheCookie")("Cookie1")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Request.Cookies.Get("TheCookie").Values.Get("Cookie1")
Request.Cookies.Get("TheCookie").Values.Get("Cookie2")
Request.Cookies.Get("TheCookie").Values.Get("Cookie3")
```

C# syntax, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

we can save it by passing as dictionary object key value pair as below.

```
 HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> val in dic)
 {
   hc[val.Key] = val.Value;
  }
 hc.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(20000));
 GetHttpResponse().Cookies.Add(hc);
```

[Example](http://goo.gl/LeSIiN)